# bool operator in c++

Tags: c++

Here is a snippet of the code that I found on my beginner file:

```
struct TriIndex       //triangle index?
{
    int vertex;       //vertex
    int normal;       //normal vecotr
    int tcoord;       //

    bool operator<( const TriIndex& rhs ) const {                                              
        if ( vertex == rhs.vertex ) {
            if ( normal == rhs.normal ) {
                return tcoord < rhs.tcoord;
            } else {
                return normal < rhs.normal;
            }
        } else {
            return vertex < rhs.vertex;
        }
    }
};
```

I've never seen a bool operator inside a struct before. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It's a less than operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: The code inside the function is evaluating if `*this` is `<` `rhs`, `bool` is merely the return type.

The operator is `operator <` which is the less than operator. The current object is considered the *left hand side* or `lhs`, and the object compared against, the right hand of the `a < b` expression is `rhs`.

```
bool  // return type
operator <  // the operator
(const TriIndex& rhs) // the parameter
{
    ...
}
```

It returns `true` if the current object is `less than` (should preceed in containers, etc) the object after the `<` in an expression like:

```
if (a < b)
```

which expands to

```
if ( a.operator<(b) )
```

There *is* a bool operator:

```
operator bool () const { ... }
```

which is expected to determine whether the object should evaluate as true:

```
struct MaybeEven {
    int _i;
    MaybeEven(int i_) : _i(i_) {}
    operator bool () const { return (_i & 1) == 0; }
};

int main() {
    MaybeEven first(3), second(4);
    if (first) // if ( first.operator bool() )
        std::cout << "first is even\n";
    if (second) // if ( second.operator bool() )
        std::cout << "second is even\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  bool operator<( const TriIndex& rhs )
```

This line of code is defining a  comparison of ***user-defined datatypes***. Here `bool` is the *type* of the value this definition will return i.e. `true` or `false`.

---

```
 const TriIndex& rhs
```

This code is telling the compiler to use *struct object* as a parameter.

---

```
if ( vertex == rhs.vertex ) {
        if ( normal == rhs.normal ) {
            return tcoord < rhs.tcoord;
        } else {
            return normal < rhs.normal;
        }
    } else {
        return vertex < rhs.vertex;
    }
```

The above code is defining criteria of the comparison i.e. how the compiler should compare the two when you say `struct a < struct b` . This is also called **Comparison Operator Overloading**.

---

TL-DR;
So after defining the operator when you write a code say:

```
if (a < b) {
.......
}
```

where a and b are of type `struct fam`. Then the compiler will do the *if else* operations inside the *definition* and use the return value . If `return = true` then (a < b) is *true* otherwise the condition will be *false*.

Answer (score 0):

That code allows you to compare different TriIndexes with the < operator:

```
TriIndex alpha;
TriIndex beta;

if (alpha < beta) {
   etc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bool operator<( const TriIndex& rhs )` is the "less than" operating (`<`), `bool` is the return type of the "less than" operator.

C++ allows you to override operators such as `<` for structs and classes.  For example:

```
struct MyStruct a, b;
// assign some values to members of a and b

if(a < b) {
    // Do something
}
```

What does this code do?  Well it depends on how the "less than" operator has been defined for `MyStruct`.  Basically, when you do `a < b` it will call the "less than" operator for that struct with `b` being `rhs` (right hand side) or whatever you call the first parameter, although `rhs` is the typical convention.